# Apex - How to parse json response to a map

Tags: apex, json, map, parser

I am getting a json response from an API call.

```
System.debug('result is : ' + responseToken.getBody())
```

//This response.body format is as below:

```
{
"email":"are02@gmail.com",
"LastName":"ABCD",
"FirstName":"ACFPY",
"Suffix":"",
"Title":"Engineer",
"Psw":"",
"PhoneCode":"",

"Phone":"100-000-000"
}
```

I want to convert this to a map so that I can get the following format:

```
new Map<String, Object>{
                        'Email' => ,
                        'firstName' => ,
                        'lastName' =>    
                        }
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this specific JSON, you can also deserialize straight into a Map:

```
Map<String, String> values = (Map<String, String>)
    JSON.deserialize(responseToken.getBody(), Map<String, String>.class);
```

From there, you can easily get the values back out:

```
String email = values.get('email');
```

Answer (score 3):

JSON class has deserializeUntyped method that converts JSON to map.

Sample code:

```
String jsonInput = '{"email":"are02@gmail.com","LastName":"ABCD","FirstName":"ACFPY","Suffix":"","Title":"Engineer","Psw":"","PhoneCode":"","Phone":"100-000-000"}';

Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
```

You can read more about JSON parsing here.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm

Comment: How to get values from this map ?

Comment: please avoid follow up questions in comments, take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour]. When opening posts on the forum, make sure you at least incldue what you have tried rather than posting requriements or how to questions. thanks